# Statusbar Translucent with Tint on Kitkat

Tags: android, statusbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I need to set Android status bar semi-translucent with a color like tint effect on iOS 7, i've reviewed the documentation, but it only explains how to get a gradient translucent status bar.

I've seen the effect on Samsung Galaxy S5 stock dialer app, so I want to perform this effect. This is the effect:

[image]

For example this is an example app that show an effect similar that I want to make, but instead a gradient to transparent I want the whole status bar with solid color behind the solid semi translucent status bar:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.readystatesoftware.systembartint.sample&hl=es

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe adding a picture of the Samsung Galaxy S5 stock dialer app would be nice?

Comment: I think this picture is SG S5 stock dialer's.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set color over the pattern #OORRGGBB?

Example: #50ff0000. The first two numbers are the opacity.

Anyway, I've found this project that might help you.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, i've also found this project, it's really close that i want to achieve, but instead the gradient effect i need a flat one.

Comment: Ok, so try to set using the color pattern as I told before. Not sure if this will work.

Comment: I've just tried your option, and didn't work as i need, anyway i found other solution similar for your recommended project, is not exactly what i want but the result is more polished (Badly what i want seems that is an TouchWiz only feature): [link](http://blog.gauntface.co.uk/2014/01/10/translucent-theme-in-android/), it's from a Google employee blog and it's a very interesting approach. And thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the samsung dialer app gets root permissions because it's a system app. To set a flat background, you would either need root permission or somehow simulate a samsung app to gain access. I think the gradient is your best option.

You could also set your app to full screen and simulate fake system bars that change based on the device so that they look the same as the normal ones, but that would take a lot of time to make.